# Android: IOException with HttpGet request

Tags: android, http, ioexception, unknown-host

Im trying to connect to a server and than receive some data back in Json format. Here is my java code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://my.server.com/validate/" + data);
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("X-AuthToken","my authorisation code");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I also have

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
```

as a child of manifest (not application) in my manifest.xml

When I try to open the url in browser, I get the correct page but I dont get any data since it misses the authentication. I also have a good connection.

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now, but I still get IOException at the line with client.execute(request)

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: my.server.com
```

Any ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: try hitting a known site like `http://www.google.com` see if you get the same result, if so you know that the problem is with connecting to internet for some reason. If not then you know problem is with your  specific server

Comment: Are you running the app on Android 3.0 or higher?

Comment: I tryed google, the same result. Im running on Android 2.3.3

Comment: Oh ok, that shouldn't give a problem then. in 3.0 and higher you must put it in a Async task, else it won't work. But like I said, that is only in 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you're missing `uses-`?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`?

`<permission>` is used to declare a new permission. [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms)

Comment: wow, that was pretty stupid of me...I usually write manifest file manualy, this time I used the Eclipse GUI for it...anyway, that fixed the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Inside of eclipse manifest GUI, on Permissions tab. After you click `Add...` you need to choose `uses-permission` which is the bottom on on the list

Comment: Yeah, it is unnecessarily confusing :/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm missing something, but is `my.server.com` really a valid host?  Did you forget to plug in the actual host?

Comment: No, I have the real host in my code, I just put "my.server.com" here so it's clearer, since the real url is quite long

Comment: So you replaced the actual host name in both the example Java code and the exception message?

Comment: Also, when you access that page via URL in a browser, are you doing that from the mobile device or a separate computer?  Might want to make sure the mobile device is on the same network connection.

Comment: yes, the real url is: https://jep.staging.jochen-schweizer.de/rest/voucher/validate/

Comment: Im accesing it on the same phone im running the app

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answers here, here are a few aditional suggestions

1. Try going to to URL in a browser
2. Check to make sure you have an internet connection on your device by using the browser
3. Try cleaning the project and trying again (this has done the trick for me several times)  (Project -> Clean)